# Get width of parent element in .Net maui

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I am trying to draw a `Line` in a `VerticalStackLayout` in .net Maui.
I want the line to stretch from left to right.

Is there a way to get the size of the parent element?
I tried it with the WidthRequest which results in nothing because it wasn't set.

```
   <Line X1="0"
            Y1="0"
            X2="{ Binding Source={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=WidthRequest}"
            Y2="0"
            StrokeLineCap="Round"
            Stroke="{StaticResource Icon}"
            StrokeThickness="1"
          AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="70,0"
          BackgroundColor="Gray"/>
```

Comment: i test your code inside a grid with <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto" ColumnDefinitions="Auto"> As parent and it works as expected!

Comment: What happens if you do `.., Path=Width}"` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, that the `Line` was in a `VerticalStackLayout` which was in an `AbsoluteLayout` and this won't pass its size down, which means that the `HorizontalOptions` and `VerticalOptions` have no effect on the `VerticalStackLayout`
[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/absolutelayout). [image]

My Solution is as follows:

**Either the Line is in the AbsoluteLayout itself**

```
<Line X1="0"
        Y1="0"
        X2="0"
        Y2="0"
        StrokeLineCap="Round"
        Stroke="{StaticResource Icon}"
        StrokeThickness="1"

        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="70,0,1,1"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="WidthProportional"
        BackgroundColor="Gray"/>
```

With the combination of `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="70,0,1,1"` and `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="WidthProportional"`, the `Line` stretches from left to right.

**Or the Line is in the VerticalStackLayout, which then needs to use the AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds**

```
  <VerticalStackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Hours}"
                         AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="WidthProportional"
                         AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
                         >
```

With the combination of `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="WidthProportional"` and `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"`, the `VerticalStackLayout` stretches to the width of the `AbsoluteLayout`.

If my control wasn't in an AbsoluteLayout it would have worked as [Leandro Toloza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14322498/leandro-toloza) stated in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I am using x:Reference like:

```
<VerticalStackLayout x:Name="vLayout">
    <Line X2="{Binding Source={x:Reference vLayout}, Path=Width}" Stroke="Black"></Line>
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

(you don't need to set X1, Y1 and Y2 because they are 0 by default)

You just have to give the parent element a name, and it works fine.